# backup blackberry application data programmatically

Tags: blackberry, backup, messenger, memo

I'm developing an application in blackberry to backup its data, BBM chats, memos, tasks, calender notes, password keeper data etc. which can be synchronized with other blackberry phones (in case a user purchases a new blackberry device). How can I proceed? Please give me some ideas/code to backup the above data. Also, I've come to know that the BBM doesn't allow its chats to be accessed. And how can we access password keeper data and how to backup all these data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, you will not be able to. BBM doesn't allow access for security reasons, and should be tied to a BlackBerry account anyway.

I should think that it is a similar situation for Password Keeper.

Comment: Thanks for your response biddulph.r . How can I then backup tasks, calendar notes etc. ?

Comment: You can get access to some of the native data stores. See http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Task_list_565511_11.jsp for examples for accessing tasks using the javax.microedition.pim.PIM classes, and other areas on the left bar inclulding calendar, contacts etc.